# Meaning of "induce of" in letters by Thomas Jefferson

Tags: differences, verbs, meaning-in-context

> [March 24th 1789](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%22induce%20of%22&s=1111311111&sa=&r=1&sr=)
>
> In Europe I doubt whether you can; because our government gives it’s offices on it’s own knowledge of persons, and not on the recommendations of others. They give their diplomatic appointments with more caution too because of the distance at which they are to be exercised and the necessity which that **induces of** leaving to them a great latitude of discretionary power.

---

> [May 25th 1795](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%22induce%20of%22&s=1111311111&sa=&r=2&sr=)
>    Dear Sir
>
> My last to you was of Dec. 23. 1793. Since that I have received yours of Nov. 7. 11. 13. 1794. May 22. 1795. Jan. 29. My not having written to you so long a time is to be ascribed with truth to the eagerness and activity with which I am pursuing my agricultural reformations, to the habit which this has **induced of** procrastinating every thing which will bear procrastination, and to the circumstance that my communications to you would bear it, as there was no change in the state of your affairs till lately.

1. What does **to induce of** mean? I found the definition of *induce* at [Oxford Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/induce?q=induce), but it does not clarify it for me.
2. Is there a difference between **induce of** and *induce*?

Comment: You're parsing these wrong. The first is parsed: "the necessity () of leaving to them" and the second "to the habit () of procrastinating". The phrases "which that induces" and "which this has induced" modify "necessity" and "habit".

Comment: @PeterShor: +1. Thank you very much. Please feel free to recast your comment into an answer for which I can upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you know what 'to induce' means.

One must bear in mind that Thomas Jefferson was writing in the late-eighteenth century. The grammar forms which we take for granted, on both sides of the Atlantic, were not nearly as standardised and established as they are today.

Having said all that, the way Jefferson uses 'to induce of procrastinating' is not much different to the way anyone might use it today. The 'of' is not really connected to the verb 'induce' but to the subsequent gerund in each case.

Consider: 'The problem with my road accident is the habit this has induced, of driving everywhere at 20 mph.' Now alter it slightly and say 'Since my accident I am in the habit of driving at 20mph'. The 'of' remains. It has nothing to do with 'induce'. It is the 'of' which precedes a present participle used as a noun (gerund) as in:

'I have a way of working'
'She has a manner of speaking'
'It has engendered in him a fear of flying'

And this in turn is no different to saying 'I am afraid of spiders'.

So, in my view Jefferson's use of the preposition 'of' has nothing to do with the verb 'induce'. The 'of' would have been there no matter what verb he had employed. He might have said 'to the habit which this has encouraged of procrastinating...'

I have no doubt that Professor John Lawler will be able to explain this far better, and more technically than I can.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of induce is the same. Try to imagine a comma or semicolon right after the 'induce'

> They give their diplomatic appointments with more caution too because of the distance at which they are to be exercised and the necessity which that induces of leaving to them a great latitude of discretionary power.

because of the distance at which they (the diplomatic appointments) are exercised a necessity is induced - this necessity is leaving them to a great latitude of discretionary power

> My not having written to you so long a time is to be ascribed with truth to the eagerness and activity with which I am pursuing my agricultural reformations, to the habit which this has induced of procrastinating every thing which will bear procrastination, and to the circumstance that my communications to you would bear it, as there was no change in the state of your affairs till lately.

eagerness and activity with which he was pursuing his agricultural reformations induced  the habit of procrastinating everything which will bear procrastination...